# JMenuItem triggers listener action only when JMenu is clicked afterwards

Tags: java, swing

The relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
public MenuBar(Frame f) {
        
        JMenu _file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu _open = new JMenu("Open");

        JMenuItem _studenti = new JMenuItem("Studenti");

    _studenti.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }

    _open.add(_studenti);   
    _file.add(_open);
    add(_file);
```

Even though the action is tied to _studenti, _file needs to be pressed before anything can happen. I read that Action is supposed to be used instead of ActionListener, but I want to avoid making that change if it's possible. If it is necessary, which change would I need to make?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Why is important that `_file` generate some kind event?

Comment: I'm trying to trigger the action on _studenti immediately so that i don't have to click on _file after to make the change happen

Comment: Use a `JToolBar` instead

Comment: Can't, according to my assignment

Comment: *"The relevant part of my code.."* For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: @Anja The problem you have is, a `JMenu` is container, it's not meant to be an "actionable" item, it makes no sense, why would a menu perform an action?  You're also running up against established UX which dictates that a "menu" presents "options" - it's kind of been that way for nearly 50 years, rightly or wrongly, this is the established expectations.  So to answer your question, no, there's not an appropriate way/mechanism to achieve what you're trying to do and if there's a hack or work around, I'd certainly not be the one to show you - sorry.

Comment: @Anja I would, personally, instead, add `_studenti` directly to `_file`, if required make it read "Open student..." or something

Comment: That makes a lot of sense haha, thank you for explaining!